# Setting max date on datepicker not working

Tags: c#, jquery, date, datepicker

I currently trying to set  `maxDate` on a `datepicker` and `maxDate: '<%= courseEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") %>'`

But when set on datepicker,

```
$('#<%= tbStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    minDate: 0,
                    maxDate: '<%= courseEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") %>',
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
                        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
                    },
                    onSelect: function (date) {

                        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
                        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

                        $('#<%= tbEndDate.ClientID %>').datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);

                    }

                });
```

Datepicker whole calendar becomes disabled. I tried alert the maxDate and

`<%= courseEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") %>` gives me `'24-12-16'`. So everything seems ok to me, but the calendar is disabled..

May I know why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Why would `24-12-16` be a valid setting for a datepicker that has a format of `24-December-2016` ?

You're going to have to parse that date from the given format to a date object

```
$('#<%= tbStartDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-y','<%= courseEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yy") %>'),
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
    },
    onSelect: function(date) {

        var selectedDate = new Date(date);
        var msecsInADay = 86400000;
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);

        $('#<%= tbEndDate.ClientID %>').datepicker("option", "minDate", endDate);
    }
});
```